# How can this Python code be written without the one line for loop?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, hex, rgb

I saw a function that converts Hexadecimal color codes to RGB ones. but I didn't understand it quite well. How could it would've been written with a multi-line for loop? also what's this line doing:
`hex[i:i + 2], 16`

```
def hex_to_rgb(hex):
    return tuple(int(hex[i:i + 2], 16) for i in (0, 2 ,4))
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, have you tried searching for "list/tuple/dict comprehensions"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All it does is get red, green & blue value from the hex convert it to integer & return them as tuple
https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/how-hex-to-rgb.html

```
def hex_to_rgb(hex):
    rgb_lst = []
    for i in (0, 2, 4):
        hex_int = int(hex[i: i + 2], 16) # convert to base 16 int
        rgb_lst.append(hex_int)
    return tuple(rgb_lst)
```

Comment: you mean `rgb_list.append(hex_int)`, right? `list` has no `push` method. Also `for i in (0, 2, 5)` should be `for i in (0, 2, 4)` as in the OP question, that's not `range`

Comment: `for i in (0, 2, 4)` also work so does `for i in range(0, 5, 2)`

Comment: Works well, but why are you adding hex_int to the empty list? Also what's the value of hex_int?

Comment: for rgb we need three values of red green & blue. suppose hex is `FF0000` color red. so the first values would be `255, 0, 0` for hex_int. we append these in rgb_lst that  would be `[255, 0, 0]`

Comment: Okay got it. Thank you